# Retaining the current page of t:dataScroller when returning after postback

Tags: jsf, tomahawk, datascroller

Having the next **table/paginator** combination working properly, does somebody know what I have to do to remain on the **current page** after 'someAction' gets fired?

(Because, actually returns ever to the first page.)

```
<t:dataTable id="myTable" ...
    ...
</t:dataTable> 

<t:dataScroller id="myScroller" for="myTable" ...
    ...
</t:dataScroller

<h:commandButton action="#{someBean.someAction}" ... />
```

Thanks!

Comment: I mean that, if I navigate to the third page, for example, then I hit the button, the action is executed, but I always return to the first page. Thanks

Comment: Right, I clarified the title. Pagination != Navigation.

Comment: BalusC, as you said previously, declaring 'someAction' as void (not String) do the thing. Thanks a lot!